# Ошибка в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вот собственно код:

```
preg_replace('/?_\d*/','',$string);
```

Ошибка:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in ...
```

Искал в интернете, говорят что из-за квантификатора повторения.
Но как исправить это тогда исправить?

Comment: вопросик что у вас означает?

Comment: А все, понял намек. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Нет, проблема не в квантификаторе, а в символе `"?"`. Дело в том, что этот метасимвол означает "может быть, а может не быть", т.е. для регулярного выражения `"/\d\_\d?/"` подходят строки "1_1" и "1_", у вас знак вопроса стоит сразу после границы регулярного выражения и машина не понимает как трактовать знак вопроса. Если вы пытаетесь заменить такую строку "?_12345" на пустоту, тогда вам надо экранировать знак вопроса и конечный регэксп будет выглядеть так: `"/\?\_\d*/"`. Если преследовалась другая цель, то напишите пример строчки и то, что вы хотите из неё вырезать.